# Secrecy rate of eavesdropper channel?

Tags: information-theory, cryptography, security

I want to find secrecy rate of a main channel in case of Gaussian broadcast channel. e.g. I have a single transmitter and a receiver where eavesdropper wants to eavesdrop the communication over secondary channel. What will be the information rate, so eavesdropper can be kept ignorant of sent message

Comment: [Also posted on Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172865/secrecy-rate-of-main-channel). [Please do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: It would help to make your question self-contained by showing us the definition of the channel and of secrecy rate and of information rate.  Also it would help to tell us your thoughts and what research you have done.  You might want to do some reading about the subject: see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information-theoretic_security#Physical_layer_encryption for some references to get you an entry point to the literature, and do some research to read about Wyner's wiretap channel.